# Minor differences in background-image positions across browsers

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, browser, safari

On http://onpole.org/roland/, I have used background-images to decorate the page. 
I, myself, use Mozilla Firefox, so I created my CSS with that browser in mind.

However, if I open the same website in different browsers (Chrome, Safari, have not tried IE yet) I see minor differences, which disrupt the layout.

Examples:

(this one actually is wrong in Firefox)

At the top of the page, there is a drawing, in which a white line comes out and goes down, into the next part of the website.
In Firefox there is an error when it comes to the next part, 
[image: see this]

But in Safari and Chrome this line is correct!

[image: See this]

I would post more examples, but apparantly my reputation is too low to post more than 2 links. There goes being specific.

There's also a part where there are arrows coming out of the line. This works fine in Firefox, but has an error in both Safari and Chrome.

So the first error is not correct in Firefox but works fine in Safari and Chrome.
The second error is exactly the other way around.

I am posting this here because I need advice on how to tackle these problems. 
Should I make browser specific css where I move the line 1 pixel?
Or is there some other way? Or do any of you know why these differences occur?

Comment: Slicing up images like that and then trying to align them back together again is a recipe for disaster and is best avoided. There are ways to get those background colors working while keeping the line images intact, so I'd recommend you pursue that avenue.

Comment: I think I see what you mean. I can just not slice the images up, and that way they will align ofcourse. But there is one part in the website which can grow/shrink in height, so there the white line has to be repeatable. Which, I think, can still be a problem. Right?

Comment: I guess that is a problem. I'd either look at rethinking what you expect to happen, or perhaps experiment with the `background-size` property.

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion but why not create a separate stylesheet? When I helped redesign my company's website, my supervisor and I found that our stylesheet rendered properly in Chrome but not in Firefox. Ultimately we created a stylesheet to fix those areas. It would only launch if the browser being used was Firefox.

Using a simple `PHP` command (and assuming that your `Gecko` stylesheet will be stored in a folder called *CSS* in your site's main template directory), here's how you can detect if the browser being used is Firefox which will then force the `Gecko` stylesheet to launch before the page is even loaded:

```
// firefox
if ($this['useragent']->browser() == 'firefox') {

  // add gecko stylesheet
  $this['asset']->addFile('css', 'css:gecko.css');

}
```

**Important:** When writing a stylesheet meant for Gecko-based browsers only, **the sheet must be written as follows**:

```
@-moz-document domain(YOUR-DOMAIN.com) {

  /* ADD YOUR CSS HERE */

}
```

Only the code in between the `{ }` will be read in Firefox. The best thing of all is if you want to target specific subdomains on your site, you can add a declaration for that subdomain all on the same stylesheet.

```
@-moz-document domain(YOUR-DOMAIN.com) {

  /* ADD YOUR CSS HERE */

}

@-moz-document domain(SUBDOMAIN.YOUR-DOMAIN.com) {

  /* ADD YOUR CSS HERE */

}
```

Just remember to keep your rules inside the curly `{ }` brackets and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, and yes this would work. But I found out that the differences are not constant. For example; I just fixed an error in FireFox, then changed the size of my browser a little bit, and there the error was again! So even if I make seperate style sheets, the problems will still be there..